Facing difficulty in upgrading chain_spec to polkadot-v1.4.0
I am currently upgrading my chain to Polkadot v1.4.0, and I encountered an issue related to the ENDOWMENT value in chain_spec.rs(Please refer Screenshot). When I set the ENDOWMENT to 10^21, the chain fails to run. However, when I change the value to 10^20, everything works fine, and the chain operates as expected.

Could anyone help me understand why setting ENDOWMENT to 10^21 causes this issue, and what might be the underlying problem? Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this while keeping the higher ENDOWMENT value would be greatly appreciated.
Additional Information:
Polkadot version: v1.4.0
The issue occurs when attempting to run the chain with an ENDOWMENT of 10^21.
Thank you in advance!
Note: I'm able to run same chain_spec file successfully with version 1.7.0.

I try to replicate your issue. It is working as expected.
My polkadot version is: 1.9.0
...
    const UNITS: Balance = 1_000_000_000_000_000_000_00;
    const ENDOWMENT: Balance = 10_000_000_000 * UNITS;
    serde_json::json!({
        "balances": {
            "balances": endowed_accounts.iter().cloned().map(|k| (k, ENDOWMENT)).collect::<Vec<_>>(),
        },
 ...


Let's try another version

Yeah I tried with version 1.7.0 and it working but not with 1.4.0 what can be the issue?
